# First time user of AWS. How to interpret this error message for images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm setting up a development environment for a project that I will be working on for the time being. I've got my development setup working for the most part and have gotten my rails app to run on local host. However, I have a slight problem and I'm hoping that someone can point me on the right path.

Before I start, I'm using Rails 2.3 (we're in the midst of updating) and AMAZON Web Services for images. Ive been given a key and have been instructed to place it in my var/local.config/file_name.yml file. Below I've placed the AWS keys that were given to me:

```
s3_access_key: ABCDERFGHIJSKLM (not the actual keys)
s3_secret_access_key:ZYXWVTUV
```

When I load the web page under port 3000 I have a few images that do not show up and when I check the console I see this error message:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 111.111.11.1111) [GET]

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/attachments/0003/5697/os64_small.png"  
with {:method=>:get}):
actionpack (2.3.18) lib/action_controller/routing/recognition_optimisation.rb:66:in 
`recognize_path'
actionpack (2.3.18) lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:442:in `recognize'
actionpack (2.3.18) lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:437:in `call'
actionpack (2.3.18) lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
```

My main problem is that I'm trying to deduce where to pursue this problem.

- I'm certain I have the right keys
- All the other images are loading on the page except for a select few

I'm trying to gauge where the problem could be? I would naturally think that something is wrong with AWS because the images are stored there. The error message says ApplicationController#index but this is a huge repository to look for. I'm trying to find where best to look. Some guidance would be appreciated. I've never used it before and I'm trying to decide if this is a problem I can solve on my end or if its on their end. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/attachments/0003/5697/os64_small.png"
>   with {:method=>:get})

You may have other issues with your code, but this isn't an AWS error. The exception is being raised because Rails has a problem with your `routes.rb`: specifically, Rails doesn't think it has a route that matches the resource described by the relative URL in the error.

Check the output of `rake routes`, and refer to the [Inspecting and Testing Routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#inspecting-and-testing-routes) section of "Rails Routing from the Outside In" for additional guidance on routing. That should at least get you started.

Comment: Thanks CodeGnome. That narrows it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your using to upload your images, but I personally use paperclip. Alot of times after making changes with paperclip I'll have to re upload pictures I've already loaded to see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I was missing a s3 environment variable somewhere in my config logic.